# how to make my application appears in the "open with" menu in windows by java

Tags: java, windows, menu, jar, exe

I've made an application by java similar to `notepad` as a `jar` file then I make it `exe` file,,so what I want is to make this application appears in the right-click windows menu in the `open with` menu that can open for example any text file..
For example I have a text file on the desktop then when I right click on it and click open with `my application` should appear with the other available programs that can run this kind of files..
What should I do !

Comment: You need to be able to add an entry to the registry

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows has a thing called a "registry". It's an ancient and problematic system component that stores a wide range of data related to your computer, users, installed software, configuration and much more.

Part of the function of the registry is to associate file extensions (say, ".txt") with programs that can process files with that extension.

You've made an executable, and that's great. Now you need to tell windows that your executable can process files ending in certain letters. To do that you must modify the registry.

You could look into doing that with Java (there are answers here on SO) but I suggest that if your application is for consumption by other people, then the usual "done thing" on windows is to have an installer. My favourite is InnoSetup - free, fast, high quality.

Whichever tool you use (even a shell script) can set registry entries for you.

Comment: Okay @Andrew thanks for your explanation that was useful for me :)

Comment: but I have one more question ,, how can I make my application open text file if I click **open with** my application!!

Comment: It's managed by exactly the same mechanism. Make an installer or script and see if that does it. If it doesn't, it's a new problem.

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood you. You mean "if my program is invoked by clicking on an icon or using 'open with' then how do I modify my program to work?"  The answer is to look at the arguments your main function receives.

Comment: `public static void main(String args[]) {
       
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try 
                {
                    new PadFrame();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(PadFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }`

Comment: Pasting a code block into a comment isn't super useful, and pasting it without any comment or question is somewhat more problematic. In any case, you want to do something with the "args" array.